# Python BigQuery Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Recently I'm receiving these errors, trying to modify query_job.result parameters page_size, timeout

and also setting Retry handler with deadline=240.

however somewhere at the background of bigquery's library there is request with timeout=60 I can't change.

I've been using this code for 6 month and this week is the first time I got this error.

I tried to add the bqstorageclient option, pandas gbq downloader, and to_dataframe with bqstorageclient

How should I configure the query to get all the data?

```py
import google.api_core.retry.Retry
bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(
    credentials=credentials
)
r = Retry(deadline=240)
query_job = client.query("select * from `table_name`") # client(bigquery client) 

# tried without any params, with page_size=1,100,500,1000 and timeout=60,120,240
rows = query_job.result(timeout=240, page_size=500, retry=r) 

data = [r for r in rows]
# df = pd.read_gbq("select * from `table_name`", use_bqstorage_api=True)
# df = rows.to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Which "google-cloud-bigquery" Python version are you using? There seems to be a known issue related to this with the 1.24.0 version:  https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/40
In case you're using that version, maybe you could try downgrading to a lower version and see if that mitigates this behavior.

Comment: It first occurred when I accidentally updated to 1.24.0, but then I downgraded back to 1.22.0 and the error kept popping when downloading same results

Comment: That's strange, according to the issue, downgrading to a lower version should mitigate that behavior. Just as a test, could you try downgrading to version 1.19.0? That's the version that the reporter had and it was working fine before upgrading.
Additionally, if you're using pip, you could try deleting the "1.24.0" package version and then install the "1.19.0" version using flag "--no-cache-dir" flag, just to make sure that your environment is getting a fresh package installation.

Comment: downgrading to `pip install google-cloud-bigquery==2.1.0` fixed my issue.

Comment: I'm using` google-cloud-bigquery==1.18.1` and `pandas-gbq==0.15.0` but am experiencing the random issue as well